# Get number from the string JS / Lodash / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have a link that comes in as a string, for example:

```
 let data = [
         '/api/customer’,
         '/api/customer/123’,
         '/api/customer/123/details’
    ];
```

I need to extract the numeric ID if there is one. The only way I found is trough _.isNaN():

```
const myStrArray = type.split('/');
const numericsArray = _.filter(myStrArray, urlPart => !_.isNaN(parseInt(urlPart, 10)));
const id = numericsArray[0]; // undefined/123
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about regex? This is the normal way of processing URL parameters.

Comment: Pls, note '123' are not the only possible numbers...

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate the array with [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (or lodash [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap)), and use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a RegExp to get a sequence of numbers.

**Note:** this RegExp assumes that these are the only numbers in the string. You might want to fine tune it, if there's a possibility for other numbers.

```js
 let data = [
   '/api/customer',
   '/api/customer/123',
   '/api/customer/123/details'
];

const result = data.flatMap(str => str.match(/\d+/));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

User regex and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) like so. You need to use `||[]` in case a number was not found.

```js
const data = [
  '/api/custome',
  '/api/customer/123',
  '/api/customer/123/details'
];

const res = data.map(a=>a.match(/\d+/)||[]).flat();

console.log(res);
```